# using custom attribute in indexed BufferGeometry [three.js]

Tags: indexing, three.js, shader, custom-attributes, buffer-geometry

I have an indexed bufferGeometry which have `position` , `appear` attributes
I had set appear attribute to is the vertex appear in camera or not.
I want to use it for check if my line should be render or not
I want my line rendered if at least one of it's Vertices appear in camera.

I had wrote this without indexing (using every vertex several times) before using  discard in fragment shader but now with indexing I have problem and they will not disappear
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: sorry , that was my mistake. I should use needsUpdate of the custom attribute. Thanks